# jQuery advance to tab based on checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I'm trying to make jQuery tabs go to a certain tab based on if a checkbox is checked. The code I have used to advance one tab is this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");

    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
});
```

Then I used this to check if a certain checkbox is checked and advance to the next tab accordingly.

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected"); 

    if($("#fragment-2 input[type='checkbox'][name='1 inch Pump with Meter(includes Hose and Nozzle)']").is(':checked')){
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 3);

    }   
    else {
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
    }
});
```

This works fine. However, after the link is clicked I want it to go back to advancing by 1. The way my code is it keeps advancing by 3. How do I reset my link back to 1? Let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: could you put this in a jsfiddle

Comment: Here is an example of it on jsfiddle. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LE4EM/2/)  On the second tab 'pumps' select the second option and it will advance by 3, but it keeps advancing by 3. How do I get it to go back to 1 after Next has been clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understood it correctly then you are asking that if the next tab link on the pump tab is clicked it should advance by 3 if the option in question is clicked other wise it should advance by 1 like all the other next tab links. If that is so I would change the html to identify the next tab link by giving it an id like `fragment2next` on the pump panel  so that I can isolate events for just that link. Then in the event handler if the link is clicked and the option selected advance by 3 otherwise advance by 1.

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
    if($("#fragment-2 input[type='checkbox'][name='1 inch Pump with Meter(includes Hose and Nozzle)']").is(':checked') && ($(this).attr('id') == 'fragment2next')){
            $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 3);            
        }   
        else {
            $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
        }
});
    });
```

here is a link to the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LE4EM/5/

Comment: Thanks for the response Warrenn. What I'm looking for is this. Since that checkbox in fragment-2 includes a hose and nozzle I want the nexttab link to skip the hose and nozzle tabs, fragment-3 & 4 and go vent-cap, fragment-5 But once at fragment-5 I want it to continue to advance by 1. When I add the selected+3 it does advance by three to fragment-5 but then it wants to continue advancing by 3. How do I get it to go back to advancing by 1? Does that make it any more clear?

Comment: are you saying that all the next tab links should advance by 1 except the next tab link in the pump tab which should advance by 3 if the '1 inch Pump with Meter(includes Hose and Nozzle' is checked or advance by 1 if not. If so I have updated my answer and provided a link to the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LE4EM/3/).